# Environment variable not passed to Subviews

Tags: swift, watchkit, swiftui

I want to get started with Core Data & SwiftUI and therefore created a new watchOS project using the latest Xcode 11.1 GM.

Then, I copied both `persistentContainer` & `saveContext` from a fresh iOS project (with Core Data enabled), to gain Core Data capabilities.

After that I modified the `HostingController` to return `AnyView` and set the variable in the environment.

```
class HostingController: WKHostingController<AnyView> {
    override var body: AnyView {
        
        let managedObjectContext = (WKExtension.shared().delegate as! ExtensionDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        

        return AnyView(ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, managedObjectContext))
    }
}
```

Now I can access the context inside the `ContentView`, **but not in its sub views**.
But thats not how it is intended to be? As far as I know, all sub views should inherit its environment from its super views, right?

Right now, to access it inside its sub views I simply set the environment variables again, like this:

## ContentView.swift

```
NavigationLink(destination: ProjectsView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, managedObjectContext)) {
    HStack {
        Image(systemName: "folder.fill")
        Text("Projects")
    }
}
```

Once I remove the .environment() parameter inside ContentView, the App will crash, because there is no context loaded?!

The error message is `Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x804795e0>`.

## ProjectsView.swift

```
struct ProjectsView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    [...]
}
```

But again, that can't be right? So, whats causing the error here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to solve this by fixing up `HostingController` and guaranteeing the CoreData stack was setup before view construction. First, let's make sure the CoreData stack is ready to go. In `ExtensionDelegate`:

```swift
class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate {

    let persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Haha")

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
        persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            // handle this
        })
    }
}
```

I had trouble when this property was `lazy` so I set it up explicitly. If you run into timing issues, make `loadPersistentStores` a synchronous call with a semaphore to debug and then figure out how to delay nib instantiation until the closure is called later.

Next, let's fix `HostingController`, by making a reference to a constant view context. `WKHostingController` is an object, not a struct. So now we have:

```swift
class HostingController: WKHostingController<AnyView> {

    private(set) var context: NSManagedObjectContext!

    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        self.context = (WKExtension.shared().delegate as! ExtensionDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    }

    override var body: AnyView {
        return AnyView(ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context))
    }
}
```

Now, any subviews should have access to the MOC. The following now works for me:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc: NSManagedObjectContext

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(moc)")
            SubView()
        }
    }
}

struct SubView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc: NSManagedObjectContext

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(moc)")
            .foregroundColor(.red)
    }
}
```

You should see the address of the MOC in white above and in red below, *without* calling `.environment` on the `SubView`.

Comment: The `HostingController` part did it for me! Yay!

Answer (score 1):

In each view where you want to access your managedObjectContext you need to declare it like this:

`@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context: NSManagedObjectContext`

You don't set it on views, it gets passed around for you. And don't forget to import CoreData as well in those files.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm already doing. I've updated my question to be more clear about that. Once I remove the `.environment()` parameter inside `ContentView`, the App will crash, because there is no context loaded. But `ProjectsView` should inherit its environment from its super view `ContentView`

Comment: Your edited code still contains ProjectsView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, managedObjectContext) as destination. It should be ProjectView() only

Comment: Yes, because ist crashes without setting the.environment() which is the root of my question.

Comment: Does it crash in canvas, simulator or on device?

Comment: The canvas is imho still very buggy. I'm talking about the simulator / device. It crashes as soon as I navigate to the ProjectsView. The error message is: `Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x804795e0>`. (But manually passing it, using the .environment() modificator works)

Comment: I think it might be the way your CoreData stack is setup and/or the fact that you erase your ContentView to AnyView (which looks unnecessary anyway)

Comment: It's actually necessary because bizarrely `WKHostingController` does not mirror `UIHostingController`. You can't instantiate the hosting controller with a pre-formed view (which would implicitly set the type of `Body`) but rather you have to _override_ it and declare the generic type yourself.